# Java design on dependency packages

Tags: java

I have 2 different packages, called `parent` and `child`. `child` has dependency on `parent`.
`parent` has a cron functionality (like initiating separate thread for property refresh using timer).

parent

```
package parent;

public class ParentExmaple {

// a separate thread calls updateProperty1, resides in parent.

    public void updateProperty1() {
        // code 
    }
}
```

child

```
package child;
import parent.ParentExample;

public class ChildExample {

    public void updateProperty2() {
        // code
    }
}
```

Now I need to add a functionality from `child` to that cron in parent. This may be ridiculous.  Is there any way to implement it?

like, I need to call `ChildExample.updateProperty2` inside the `ParentExample.updateProperty1` method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Nishant I'm hazarding a guess that it's related to the UNIX cron utility - i.e. scheduling of jobs

Comment: cron does some property refresh calls.

Comment: -1 Packages have apparently nothing to do with it. You just need an association between Parent and Child. Start learning OO, please.

Comment: @greyfairer Both parent and child are packages and both has some unique functionality. To use some of parent's child has dependancy on it. Now need to merge one of the child's functionality with parent's, thats the problem. I just gave examples for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the cron functionality core to the behaviour of the parent?  If so, override it in the child.  If not, extract the cron functionality into an external class and use composition to provide the functionality to the parent and child, then modify it as required in the child.

Bit difficult to give a more concrete answer without a concrete example.

Comment: why does child not extend parent?

Comment: It doesn't need to. Both update are individual. I just gave a small illustration on package. there are some other classes in child using parent classes.

Comment: Then the best idea I can think of is to register the child as a listener on the parent, and have the parent automatically call a refresh() method on each child registered on it.